# How to store Azure Queue messages into blob using queue trigger function app in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I tried using an azure logic app in azure to do this and it works but is costing a lot of money. (blob storage is required for analytics).

There are 2 questions for this thread

1. is it better to amend the below code to store post messages in blob storage or create a separate function app with a queue trigger to store them in blob as they come in.
2. How could I implement this with example code if possible ? I cant find much at all on this matter to make a start. so I need some help.

My current function app works and is shown below.
it takes post's and stores them in a queue real time API.
posts are sent each minute.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, queueclient: func.Out[func.QueueMessage]) -> str:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    print(req.method)

if req.method == 'GET': 
  queueclient.set('string')
  return func.HttpResponse(body='------------------------', status_code=200)

elif req.method =='POST':

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
           pass
    else:
      sharedSecret = req_body.get('secret')
    if sharedSecret =='':
        queueclient.set(json.dumps(req_body))
        return func.HttpResponse(body=json.dumps(req_body), status_code=201, headers={'content-Type': 'application/json'})
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse( 
          body="<h1>Please add sharedsecret string in the request body </h1>",
            status_code=401
        )
```

Comment: Is your eventual goal is to save the data in blob storage? How big input data can be?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp provides examples for queue triggered functions(input binding) and  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp provides an example of writing to blob using output binding.  A queue is good if you have or want a asynchronous/loose coupling between post acceptance and write to blob. But if the post frequency is low and if you can afford to have synchronous processing then it's easier to have 1 function do both the tasks.

Comment: 64 KB per post message to queue storage, it would be great to input directly into blob, as the limitation for queues limits me from using 100 KB. posts come in at 1 per minute per network device at approx. 400 network devices.   trying to find the right fit.

Comment: 400 post if all at one go may not allow for synchronous flow and it also depends if the devices can implement some kind of retries incase for failure. If not,asynchronous is the better option. If the message size is below 64kb, queue should be fine. Else you would need something like a service bus or event hub. Service bus and queue both provides automatic retries and poison/ DL queues . Eventhub does not. But in case of Event hub, you can directly post into Event hub without the need of a function to do this.